# Weird firefox-safari-chrome-ie8+ extension issue with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I've developed an extension for **firefox** and **google chrome**, **safari** and **ie8+**. It inserts a button into the google mail interface . The button is supposed to insert some custom text into the email footer. It works fine on all of the four if i access the **standard google mail address** (you can **watch** it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_efJg6nt9I) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELnKUsqLvFE)).

Instead, if i access gmail through **google apps**, it almost all goes down the pipe. The only addon hat works well is the google chrome one. In all the others, the button is correctly added but when i click it this doesn't add anything into the email footer and produces the following errors.

In firefox i get the following jquery error console:

```
 Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument' Source File: chrome://sendsecurefree/content/jquery.js Line: 16
```

In firebug :

```
 uncaught exception: [Exception... "Security Manager vetoed action"  nsresult: "0x80570027 (NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://sendsecurefree/content/jquery.js :: anonymous :: line 16"  data: no] Line 0
```

Also, in Safari :

```
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: toggleEncryptFooter
```

In internet explorer only composing the mail works, forwarding and replying doesn't.

Here's my jquery code that is injected into the gmail webpage :

```
function toggleEncryptFooter() {

var canvasBody = getGmailCanvasBody();

// get the button element
var documentul = getGmailCanvasDoc();
divul = jQuery(".dX.J-Jw", documentul);      
var encryptButton = divul.find("#encrypt");

//first, check if we already have an encrypt footer
var encryptFooter = jQuery("#encrypt_footer", canvasBody);
if(encryptFooter.length != 0) {
    //we have the footer inserted, delete it
    encryptFooter.remove();

    // style the button to no footer
    encryptButton.html('Enable Encryption');
    encryptButton.removeClass('downer');
    encryptButton.addClass('upper');
} else {
    //add the footer
    var doc = document;
    var head   = jQuery('head', doc);
    var textul = head.find("div#textul",head);

    // text was inserted in injectScript / gmailadder.js into head of canvas_frame
    getGmailCanvasBody().append('<div id="encrypt_footer">' + textul.html() + '</div>');     

    // style the button to footer added
    encryptButton.html('Disable Encryption');
    encryptButton.removeClass('upper');                      
    encryptButton.addClass('downer');
}
}

// gets the head element of the document
function getGmailHead(){
    var doc = document;
    var body = jQuery('head', doc);  
return body;
}

 // gets the body element of the document   
 function getGmailCanvasBody() {
var doc = document;

gmailInst = jQuery("iframe", doc);
    if(gmailInst.length==0) {
        //exit now, we are not on compose
        return null;
}
return gmailInst.contents().find('body');
 }

 // get the document object    
 function getGmailCanvasDoc() {
var doc = document;
var body = jQuery('body', doc);
var canvas_frame = jQuery('iframe#canvas_frame', body);
     if(canvas_frame.length==0) {
         //exit now, we are not on gmail
         return null;
          }

var canvas_doc = canvas_frame[0].contentDocument;

return canvas_doc;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing here but it seems to me that this might have to do with XSS/same-origin-policy. The Google Apps mail URL is probably different from the Gmail URL.

Comment: Nope . If i access the same link [link]https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#compose : the standard interface works, the one accessed through google apps doesn't on firefox and safari. BUT, the google chrome extension works on all of them

Comment: Hope i won't loose 1 week on this enervating issue !!!

Comment: Thanks ! i never knew it existed ; i'm not a rude boy ! i accepted some of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to replace

```
gmailInst = jQuery("iframe", doc);
if(gmailInst.length==0) {
    //exit now, we are not on compose
    return null;
}
```

with

```
gmailInst = jQuery("iframe.Am.Al", doc);
if(gmailInst.length==0) {
    //exit now, we are not on compose
    return null;
}
```

It seems that in the normal Google mail interface there is only one sub-iframe inside the iframe I'm working in, so **gmailInst = jQuery("iframe", doc)** does its job as long as this condition maintains.

If i activate a few labs gadgets that are implemented with iframes, then **gmailInst = jQuery("iframe", doc)** passes the first sub-iframe in the list which is probably not the one i'm looking for so i have to use extra filtering: in this case, the class name of the sub-iframe i'm searching.

Assumptions are devils in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem . Somehow!

It seemed that disabling the **Google Calendar gadget** from the labs tab in Google Apps seemed to do the job. Now everything works fine. Hope this will help someone else.